# Manage multiple nginx containers on the same host with Docker Swarm

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-swarm

I have to manage multiple identicals nginx container using them as a CDN.
Now, because this is a degree thesis work, teachers told me that i could use Docker Swarm for manage them, using a default round-robin load balancer.

My architecture is with a browser client, that CDN (multiple nginx container as proxy-cache) and a tomcat backend (hosting multimedia file).

My question is: it is possible managing that multiple containers (i've head about "replicas" in docker service) with docker swarm?

If this is possible, how do to it?

I'd like having multiple containers in the same host instead of using multiple VM.